# How can i parse that xml file with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I want to parse tha file, but value "name" in code always have a empty string.

My xml:

```
<row>
  <id>1</id>
  <AnrufenZahl>64</AnrufenZahl>
  <NameOperator>Ioan</NameOperator>
</row>
<row>
  <id>2</id>
  <AnrufenZahl>35</AnrufenZahl>
  <NameOperator>Dian</NameOperator>
</row>
<row>
  <id>3</id>
  <AnrufenZahl>50</AnrufenZahl>
  <NameOperator>Bob</NameOperator>
</row>
```

and my JS file
I don`t have output from "alert" function.

```
$(document).ready(function () { // load xml file using jquery ajax
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "m.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
//            var output = '<ul>';
            $(xml).find('row').each(function(){
                    $(this).find("NameOperator").each(function(){
                            var name = $(this).text(); 
                            alert(name);
                    });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: why should `name` find anything? Your tag is `<NameOperator>` tag searches are done on the tag name as a WHOLE, not a substring match.

Comment: I made mistake, sorry, but code still not working. with NameOperator also

Comment: Can you just try `console.log(this);` just before line `$(this).find("NameOperator").each(function(){` and see what exactly is your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, the issue is `xml` is invalid. Adjust to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rows>
<row>
  <id>1</id>
  <AnrufenZahl>64</AnrufenZahl>
  <NameOperator>Ioan</NameOperator>
</row>
<row>
  <id>2</id>
  <AnrufenZahl>35</AnrufenZahl>
  <NameOperator>Dian</NameOperator>
</row>
<row>
  <id>3</id>
  <AnrufenZahl>50</AnrufenZahl>
  <NameOperator>Bob</NameOperator>
</row>
</rows>
```

then use `xml.documentElement`

```
$(xml.documentElement).find(..)
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/IUoarUoL7WyDAldZi4Gp?p=preview

Comment: still not working
`success: function(xml) {
                    var name = $(xml.documentElement).find("NameOperator");
                    alert(name);
    }`

Comment: @zok1995 Is `xml` valid?